# How do I refresh a tab on Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My app is running very smoothly, a major issue I'm having is that I have a save button, once clicked it saves an instance of the values entered by the user in a SQLite database locally. When I change to my other tab, it doesn't save... but if I shut the app down then reopen it its there as if there is no on click refresh through the app. also when I hit save I would like all the entry boxes the user fills in to go blank after the save button is clicked.

```
 void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindowViewModel APR = new MainWindowViewModel()
            {
                ProductName = proName.Text,
                TotalAPR = totAPR.Text,
                Total = tot.Text,
                Monthly = mon.Text
            };

            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<MainWindowViewModel>();
                int rowsAdded = conn.Insert(APR);
            }

        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<MainWindowViewModel>();
                var APRS = conn.Table<MainWindowViewModel>().ToList();

                APRListView.ItemsSource = APRS;
            }
        }
```

Above is my code for save button & appearing. Below is the xaml for save button (not sure if needed)

```
 <Button Text="Save"
                TextColor="#FFA600"
                BackgroundColor="#2B333F"
                Clicked="SaveButton_Clicked"
                FontSize="16"
                Padding="10"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                Grid.Row="14"
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Margin="0,0,0,-20"/>
```

Comment: if you are using Binding, you can just update your VM and your UI should refresh.  If you are not, then you will need to manually do something to update the UI.

Comment: @Jason I'm using Binding not sure what the next steps are though, I thought It would update as its using OnPropertyChanged

Comment: What do you expect to change?   Do you expect to see a new value in your ListView  And/or something else?

Comment: @Jason My plan is I have default values of 0 for all & one field returns nothing I'd like for when the user inserts values then saves the fields would return to the default values

Comment: The code you posted doesn't appear to use binding, although your comments says that you do.  Without seeing more of your code it's hard to say.   Based on what I can see, you should just set `proName.Text`, etc back to the defaults when you save.

Comment: Thats fair mate, Ive fixed my refresh on that page. Was missing -     BindingContext = new MainWindowViewModel();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing code in the SaveButton_Clicked Routine

```
BindingContext = new MainWindowViewModel();

        OnAppearing();
```

Full code should be

```
void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindowViewModel APR = new MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ProductName = proName.Text,
            TotalAPR = totAPR.Text,
            Total = tot.Text,
            Monthly = mon.Text
        };


        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
        {
            conn.CreateTable<MainWindowViewModel>();
            int rowsAdded = conn.Insert(APR);
        }

        DisplayAlert("Saved!", "Your APR has been saved!", "OK");

        BindingContext = new MainWindowViewModel();

        OnAppearing();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
        {
            conn.CreateTable<MainWindowViewModel>();
            var APRS = conn.Table<MainWindowViewModel>().ToList();

            APRListView.ItemsSource = APRS;


        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue now, please remember to mark your reply as answer, thanks.